# why this single charactor has 122 byte?

Tags: string, byte

I meet a stange charactor,It has 122 bytes.

```
    <script>
    var pig ="ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํ";
    alert(pig.length) ;
    </script>
```

The result is 122! oh,my god.
It make the web page disordered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a character its a string containing 122 characters, its actually 366 bytes in size. the string is made up of 3 characters, 1 `ฏ` some `๎` and the rest in `ํ`. I think they're Thai characters since chrome asks if I want to translate it from Thai.

see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/6b6VY/